# Solution for Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query which used to work as expected, recently as the amount of records have grown, somehow it returns `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`

```
SELECT `log`.id,log.account_id,log.type, 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM instagram_log as LIKES WHERE `account_id`=log.account_id AND `type`='like' AND log.target_account=LIKES.target_account AND `seen`=0 ) as has_liked, 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM instagram_log as Comments WHERE `account_id`=log.account_id AND `type`='comment' AND log.target_account=Comments.target_account AND `seen`=0 ) as has_commented, 
( SELECT information FROM instagram_log as Source WHERE `account_id`=log.account_id AND `type`='follow' AND log.target_account=Source.target_account AND `seen`=0 ) as source, 
( SELECT data FROM instagram_accounts WHERE `id`=log.account_id ) as InstagramInfo 
FROM `instagram_log` as `log` WHERE `type` = 'follow_back' AND `account_id` IN('1', '5', '2')  ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Is there something about the error message that you don't understand?

Comment: And you know which subquery is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add "LIMIT 1" in the subqueries which can return more than 1 row, or use an agregate function (MAX, MIN, GROUP_CONCAT...) in the select

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `log`.id,log.account_id,log.type, 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM instagram_log as LIKES WHERE 
`account_id`=log.account_id AND `type`='like' AND 
log.target_account=LIKES.target_account AND `seen`=0 ) as has_liked, 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM instagram_log as Comments WHERE 
`account_id`=log.account_id AND `type`='comment' AND 
log.target_account=Comments.target_account AND `seen`=0 ) as has_commented, 
( SELECT information FROM instagram_log as Source WHERE 
`account_id`=log.account_id AND `type`='follow' AND 
log.target_account=Source.target_account AND `seen`=0 limit 1) as source, 
( SELECT data FROM instagram_accounts WHERE `id`=log.account_id limit 1) as 
InstagramInfo 
FROM `instagram_log` as `log` WHERE `type` = 'follow_back' AND `account_id` 
IN('1', '5', '2')  ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 15
```

try this..